# Wordpress Multisite shares wp_posts table with postmeta

Tags: wordpress

I've been working with wordpress for a couple of years and I can say I'm a pretty advanced user.
The thing is that I am finding my self duplicating lots of wordpress sites that I created that need the exact same database and I just need to change some minor theme settings(Logo, some pages, footer/header text, title etc...).

I was reading in the documentation about multi-sites and it seems like a good solution.
What i couldn't understand is if I could use in multisite a master database that will be used for all the site I create.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you turn on the WordPress multi site feature, each site has it's own tables (wp_2_posts, etc...).

I don't think you can share the wp_posts table with different sites.

Check out this Codex page about the Multisite database structure:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Site_Specific_Tables

Cheers.